# Random pattern while animating simulated gradient in canvas element

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, html5-canvas

This is a query about something that popped up while I was experimenting with the canvas element via javascript. I wanted to have an array of points that formed a gradient which moved with time, which works perfectly apart from a bizarre pattern that comes up (only after the first wave or more), which also changes according to the number of columns and rows in the canvas (changing the size of the points just makes the patterns bigger or smaller, it's always on the same pixels.

Here's a little demo of what I mean with a bit of interface for you to mess around with, an example of the changing patterns is if the number of rows is changed to 0.75x the number of columns from the original (i.e. 40 columns, 30 rows).

http://codepen.io/zephyr/pen/GpwwWB

Javascript:

```
String.prototype.hexToRGBA = function(a) {
        function cutHex(h) {
                return (h.charAt(0) == "#") ? h.substring(1, 7) : h
        }
        var r = parseInt((cutHex(this)).substring(0, 2), 16);
        var g = parseInt((cutHex(this)).substring(2, 4), 16);
        var b = parseInt((cutHex(this)).substring(4, 6), 16);
        return 'rgba(' + r.toString() + ',' + g.toString() + ',' + b.toString() + ',' + a.toString() + ')';
}

CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.clearDrawRect = function(shape) {
        this.clearRect(shape.position.x, shape.position.y, shape.size, shape.size);
        this.fillStyle = shape.color.base;
        this.fillRect(shape.position.x, shape.position.y, shape.size, shape.size);
}

CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.render = function(render) {
        (function animate() {
                requestAnimationFrame(animate);
                render();
        })();
}

CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.renderAndThrottleFpsAt = function(fps, render) {
        var fpsInterval, startTime, now, then, elapsed;

        fpsInterval = 1000 / fps;
        then = Date.now();
        startTime = then;

        (function animate() {
                requestAnimationFrame(animate);
                now = Date.now();
                elapsed = now - then;
                if (elapsed > fpsInterval) {
                        then = now - (elapsed % fpsInterval);
                        render();
                }
        })();
}

CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.pool = {};

CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.parsePoint = function(x, y, s, c) {
        return {
                color: c,
                position: {
                        x: x,
                        y: y
                },
                size: s
        }
}

CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.fillPointsPool = function(size, cols, rows, color) {
        var i = cols;
        var j = rows;
        while(i--){
            while(j--){
                var x = i * size;
                var y = j * size;
                var a = (i * j) / (cols * rows);
                var c = {
                        hex: color,
                        alpha: a,
                        dir: 1
                };
                if (typeof this.pool.points == 'undefined') {
                        this.pool.points = [this.parsePoint(x, y, size, c)];
                } else {
                        this.pool.points.push(this.parsePoint(x, y, size, c));
                }
            }
            j = rows;
        }
}

CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.updatePointsPool = function(size, cols, rows, color) {
        this.pool.points = [];
        this.clearRect(0,0,this.canvas.width,this.canvas.height);
        this.fillPointsPool(size, cols, rows, color);
}

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// Populate Points
var size = document.getElementById('size');
var cols = document.getElementById('cols');
var rows = document.getElementById('rows');
var color = document.getElementById('color');
ctx.fillPointsPool(size.value, cols.value, rows.value, color.value);

size.oninput = function(){
    ctx.updatePointsPool(this.value, cols.value, rows.value, color.value);
}
cols.oninput = function(){
    ctx.updatePointsPool(size.value, this.value, rows.value, color.value);
}
rows.oninput = function(){
    ctx.updatePointsPool(size.value, cols.value, this.value, color.value);
}
color.oninput = function(){
    ctx.updatePointsPool(size.value, cols.value, rows.value, this.value);
}

ctx.renderAndThrottleFpsAt(60, function(){
        var i = 0;
        var len = ctx.pool.points.length;
        while (i<len) {
                var point = ctx.pool.points[i];

                // Change alpha for wave
                var delta = 0.01;
                point.color.alpha = point.color.alpha + (delta * point.color.dir);
                if (point.color.alpha > 1) {
                        point.color.dir = -1;
                } else if (point.color.alpha <= 0) {
                        point.color.dir = 1;
                }

                // Calculate rgba value with new alpha
                point.color.base = point.color.hex.hexToRGBA(point.color.alpha);
                ctx.clearDrawRect(point);
                i++;
        }
});
```

Do any of you have an idea of what's causing the pattern to appear, and any suggestions on a fix for this?

Note: I will be changing the updatePointsPool function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are forgetting to clamp your alpha values when you change the direction. The small error in the alpha value accumulates slowly producing the unwanted artifacts you see as the animation progresses.

To fix add the top and bottom limits to alpha in the code just after you add delta direction to alpha.

```
if (point.color.alpha > 1) {
    point.color.alpha = 1;  // clamp alpha max
    point.color.dir = -1;
} else if (point.color.alpha <= 0) {
    point.color.alpha = 0;  // clamp alpha min
    point.color.dir = 1;
}
```

Comment: Ah, I'd tried something similar but just setting the value had completely escaped my mind. However, I'm still curious as to how this has actually arisen, that the patterns change on how many cols and rows there are, as well as having them all in exactly the same 'color', I would have thought that not clamping it would mean that it would be more random than it is. I've made a forked pen with the solution [here](http://codepen.io/zephyr/pen/LpqPYa) because I like the pattern xD a happy little accident as Bob Ross would say

Comment: It is the starting conditions that create the pattern, it's not random and the pattern at the start is many orders of magnitude greater than any noise you will get out of floating point . Because starting value of alpha is dependent on row and col counts, and as these values are calculated from ints many share the same offset error, hence look the same.